# My app won't enter the for loop even though all conditions are satisfied

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app, for which I want a for loop to run. The for loop is inside a listview adapter, and it basically runs to get the some data from each entry of the list (hence the for loop). But, on debugging, I find that the app never enters the for loop, and just moves on to the 'if statement' given just below it. The condition that i == size of list isn't satisfied, so it should be running. Why?
This is the code :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.icu.text.UFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class SubtaskDetailAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SubtaskPartTwo> {

    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<SubtaskPartTwo> values;
    public boolean deleted;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    int ph = 10;
    int pm = 9;
    int pl = 8;
    int th = 3;
    int tm = 2;
    int tl = 1;
    private int totalTime;
    private int x;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int totaltimeints;
    int ans;

    public SubtaskDetailAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SubtaskPartTwo> list) {

        //since your are using custom view,pass zero and inflate the custom view by overriding getview

        super(context, 0 , list);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = list;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        //check if its null, if so inflate it, else simply reuse it
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_summary_item, parent, false);
        }

        //use convertView to refer the childviews to populate it with data
        TextView tvSubtaskName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvlolitaskname);
        ImageView ivPri = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivloliPri);
        ImageView ivTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivloliTime);
        TextView tvEstTaskTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEstTaskTime);
     tvSubtaskName.setText(values.get(position).getSubtaskName());

        // Algorithm

        int totaltime = values.get(position).getEstTaskTime();


         while (values.listIterator().hasNext()){
            totaltimeints += values.listIterator().next().getTime();
        }
    ans = totaltime / totaltimeints;

        if (values.get(position).getPriHigh() == 1)
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_high);
            values.get(position).setPri(ph);


        }
        if (values.get(position).getPriMed() == 1)
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_med);
            values.get(position).setPri(pm);
        }
        if (values.get(position).getPriLow() == 1)
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_low);
            values.get(position).setPri(pl);
        }

        if (values.get(position).getTimeMore() == 1)
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_more);
            values.get(position).setTime(th);
            int b = ans * th;
            tvEstTaskTime.setText(b + "");
        }
        if (values.get(position).getTimeMed() == 1)
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_med);
            values.get(position).setTime(tm);
            int b = ans * tm;
            tvEstTaskTime.setText(b + "");
        }
        if (values.get(position).getTimeLess() == 1)
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_less);
            values.get(position).setTime(tl);
            int b = ans * tl;
            tvEstTaskTime.setText(b + "");
        }

        // THIS IS WHERE I USE SORT
        Collections.sort(values, new TaskComparator());

        //return the view you inflated
        return convertView;
    }


    public void addANewSubTask(SubtaskPartTwo newSubTask) {
        add(newSubTask);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

// this doesnt work yet, fix this bug ! (same on the other adapter)
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (this.values.size()>11)
        {
            return 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return super.getCount();
        }
    }

}
```

Code for activity where the list is shown:

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class TaskSummary extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvTaskList;
    TextView tvBreak, tvBreakAfterEvery, txt1, txt2, text1, hmm;
    TextView break_duration_mins;
    ArrayList<SubtaskPartTwo> subtaskList = new ArrayList<>();
    String subtname;
    String pri;
    String time;
    int working_hours;
    int working_minutes;
    int totalTime;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    int timeInts;
    int timeConstant;
    int answer;





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tasksummary, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        dbHelper.deleteAll();

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.restore) {
            Intent inti = new Intent(this, TaskInfo.class);
            startActivity(inti);

        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_summary);






        lvTaskList = findViewById(R.id.lvTaskList);
        tvBreak = findViewById(R.id.tvBreak);
        tvBreakAfterEvery = findViewById(R.id.tvBreakAfterEvery);
        txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        break_duration_mins = findViewById(R.id.break_duration_mins);
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
        hmm = findViewById(R.id.hmm);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        working_hours = getIntent().getIntExtra("working_hours", 1);
        working_minutes = getIntent().getIntExtra("working_minutes", 0);
        int alol = working_hours * 60;
        int blol = working_minutes;
        totalTime = alol + blol;
        double without_break_hours = getIntent().getIntExtra("without_break_hours", 1);
        double without_break_minutes = getIntent().getIntExtra("without_break_minutes", 0);
        double break_duration = getIntent().getIntExtra("break_duration", 20);
        String a = working_hours + " h";
        txt1.setText(a);
        String b = working_minutes + " m";
        break_duration_mins.setText(b);
        String c = break_duration + " m";
        txt2.setText(c);



        //Mathematics

        double g = working_hours * 100;
        double h = g + working_minutes;
        double i = h + break_duration;
        double j = i / 60;
        double p = (int) j;
        double q = j - p;
        double r = q * 60;

        without_break_hours = p;
        without_break_minutes = r;

        String d = without_break_hours + " h";
        String e = without_break_minutes + " m";

        text1.setText(d);
        hmm.setText(e);

        

        Cursor res = dbHelper.getdata();
        SubtaskDetailAdapter adapter = new SubtaskDetailAdapter(this, subtaskList);
        lvTaskList.setAdapter(adapter);

        

        while (res.moveToNext() && res != null){
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < adapter.getCount(); i1++ ){
                timeInts += adapter.getItem(i1).getTime();
            }

            timeConstant = totalTime/timeInts;


            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < adapter.getCount(); i2++){
                answer = timeConstant * adapter.getItem(i2).getTime();
            }
            SubtaskPartTwo subtaskPartTwo = new SubtaskPartTwo(res.getString(0), res.getInt(1), res.getInt(2), res.getInt(3), res.getInt(4), res.getInt(5), res.getInt(6), 0, 0, answer);
            //subtaskList.add(subtaskPartTwo);

            adapter.addANewSubTask(subtaskPartTwo);
        }
        


    }



}
```

Comment: It's because your condition for running is fixed `i == values.size()` change it to be `i <= values.size()` like so `for (int i = 0; i <= values.size(); i++){`

Comment: Your code is nearly impossible to read because it's half blank lines. You also seem to be using `int` where you should have `boolean`, making it more difficult.

Comment: Agreed. But then I want the loop to stop once it has taken data from all items of the list and stored them in totaltimeints...

Comment: Kindly edit the code and make it readable and remove the unnecessary blank lines to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

Before each iteration of the [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp), program checks if the condition (`i == values.size()`) is satisfied . As `i` is equal to 0, it is not equal to `values.size()`, so the block will not be executed.

Do you want the more common `i < values.size()` or possibly `i <= values.size()`?

Comment: Agreed. But then I want the loop to stop once it has taken data from all items of the list and stored them in totaltimeints..., the loop keeps running now with the above suggestion... :(

Comment: `i < values.size()` should work as long as `values` remains fixed in size. If it doesn't work, you could try make a `ListIterator` from `values` and iterate that way.

Comment: I added the list iterator, but the app seems to freeze when in the while loop for the list iterator now.. (code given above)

Comment: Save the iterator to a variable. Then after incrementing, [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()) the value. Otherwise I believe you are adding the same value over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter's `GetView` method will be called multiple times, so it is not the correct place to put the for/while loop for totaling as you will have unexpected results. if you want to total anything put that inside the fragment or activity class where you are using the adapter to populate the recycler view. Ya, you can also set inside the constructor of the adapter too, if the ArrayList which you are passing at the time of initialization is not going to be changed.

Comment: I did that using the Activity where I am using the adapter. I removed the code from the adapter class, and did it in the activity. But it is now causing the app to crash. The code for the activity I have given above..